# referencing to a parent variable inside an object

Tags: javascript, object

I'm working on a JavaScript object and there are a lot of variables declared inside it. What I want to do is reference to another child of the parent object. Given the following object :

```
var clusters = {

    auxiliars: {
        environment         : "Development",
        local_storage_key   : "Cluster",

        iqns_class          : ".iqn",
        iqn                 : this.iqns_class.parent(),

        viewport            : $(window),

        viewport_width      : this.viewport.width(),
        viewport_height     : this.viewport.height(),

        plugin              : {
            containerID : "",
            first       : false,
            previous    : false,
            next        : false,
            last        : false,
            startPage   : 1,
            perPage     : 6,
            midRange    : 6,
            startRange  : 1,
            endRange    : 1,
            keyBrowse   : false,
            scrollBrowse: false,
            pause       : 0,
            clickStop   : true,
            delay       : 50,
            direction   : "auto",
            animation   : "fadeIn",
            links       : "title",
            fallback    : 1000,
            minHeight   : true,
            callback    : function(pages, items) {}
        }
    },

    set_local_storage_data: function(data_val) {
        return localStorage.setItem(auxiliars.local_storage_key, data_val);
    },

    get_local_storage_data: function() {
        return +(localStorage.getItem(auxiliars.local_storage_key) || 1);
    },

    set_environment: function(environment) {
        if(auxiliars.environment == "Development") {
            less.env = "development";
            less.watch();
        }
    },

    shop_iqns_selected_class: function() {
        if (auxiliars.viewport_width < 980) {
            $(auxiliars.iqns_class).each(function(index, element) {
                var element = $(element);
                $(auxiliars.iqn).on('click', function() {
                    if (element.hasClass('selected')) {
                        element.removeClass('selected');
                    } else {
                        element.addClass('selected');
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    },

    initiate_plugin: function(plugin_navigation, plugin_options) {
        var options = $.extend({}, auxiliars.plugin, plugin_options);
        return $(plugin_navigation).jPages(options);
    }

}
```

You will notice `this.viewport.width()`, by that I want to point to the `viewport` variable declared in the same `auxiliars` object. Obviously I'm getting an error, but how can I point to that child value of the same object ?

Comment: Next time please try to summarize your code example to the minimal expression that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the simplest way is to transform your autoreferent attributes in methods:

```
var clusters = {
  auxiliars: {
    viewport        : $(window),
    viewport_width  : function(){ return this.viewport.width() },
  }
}

clusters.auxiliars.viewport_width();
```

[Check the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/A628S/)

Comment: Oh, that's definitely much more elegant :)

Comment: But per say how would I go when trying to use the same principle in here: `set_local_storage_data: function(data_val) {
        return localStorage.setItem(auxiliars.local_storage_key, data_val);
    }` ?

Comment: And making `viewport_width` a function will allow it to reflect changes in the return value of `viewport.width()`.  Using a plain variable just gets the iniital width, so it would be out of sync if the width ever changes. (Not sure if that's an issue for your case, anyway, though.)

Comment: Yes I know that, that the plan since you use different devices you have different widths and I need to check that, but you won't resize anything while using a tablet per say ( that if you don't rotate the device in which case it switches from portrait to landscape or reverse ). I'm saying this because I cannot keep applying javascript functions live while the width keeps changing, what if you decide to resize your window ? That will probably make the browser crash

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to do that in JavaScript. That is, there's no way to reference the "in-progress" element being built with an object literal.

You can however reference the properties (and sub-properties) in a subsequent assignment statement.

```
var clusters = {

    auxiliars: {
        environment         : "Development",
        local_storage_key   : "Cluster",

        iqns_class          : ".iqn",
        iqn                 : this.iqns_class.parent(),

        viewport            : $(window),
        // ...

clusters.auxiliars.viewport_width = clusters.auxiliars.viewport.width();
clusters.auxiliars.viewport_height = clusters.auxiliars.viewport.height();
```

Comment: Oh, so I have no other way but declaring some other variables outside the object and calling them inside the object after the object has been declared.

Comment: Yes. There are various ways of doing it, but basically the problem is that there's no "name" for an object that is under construction.

Comment: That sucks :| Because using Prototypes it is possible, but it causes me some problems with some jQuery plugins, and I had to go with objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference part of a new object literal in other parts of the same object literal.  You can instead build those parts in separate statements:

```
var clusters = ...;
clusters.auxiliars.viewport_height = clusters.auxiliars.viewport.height();
clusters.auxiliars.viewport_width = clusters.auxiliars.viewport.width();
```

It's less elegent, but I think it's the only way to do it.